# Android Fragment state and setRetainInstance

Tags: android-fragments

Please excuse the long post. I was playing around with a simple app and wanted to save a custom object in a fragment across an orientation change. Previously within activities this used to be handled using the onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() / getLastNonConfigurationInstance() methods. Seeing as these methods are now deprecated, the documentation encourages the use of fragments and the setRetainInstance(boolean) method.

I went ahead and played around with this method and then noticed a strange difference in behaviour when it came to saving the state of the fragments across orientation change. First up, a very brief explanation of the app I was playing with:

---

### Main Activity

**Fragment A** (First fragment shown on app launch)

This is a simple fragment with 3 EditText controls. Each one has an ID in the layout file. The fragment also includes a button which when selected replaces Fragment A with Fragment B and saves the transaction on the backstack.

**Fragment B**

This is a fragment with an empty layout. If back is pushed, Fragment A is restored from the backstack.

---

### Scenarios

**Scenario A** - setRetainInstance(false):

1. App launches and fragment A is displayed.
2. I enter values into the EditText fields and select the button.
3. Fragment B is displayed. I change device orientation once and hit the back key.
4. Fragment A is displayed with the entered values (view state) intact.

**Scenario A** - setRetainInstance(true):

The same behaviour takes place as above

**Scenario B** - setRetainInstance(false):

1. App launches and fragment A is displayed.
2. I enter values into the EditText fields and select the button.
3. Fragment B is displayed. I change device orientation **twice** and hit the back key.
4. Fragment A is still displayed with the entered values (view state) intact.

**Scenario B** - setRetainInstance(true):

1. App launches and fragment A is displayed.
2. I enter values into the EditText fields and select the button.
3. Fragment B is displayed. I change device orientation **twice** and hit the back key.
4. Fragment A is displayed with empty EditText controls, i.e. none of the entered values (view state) still intact.

For some reason the use of setRetainInstance(true) interferes with the view state of fragment A (on the backstack) when the orientation changes more than once.

---

### Possible Explanation

I started getting nervous about the use of setRetainInstance while not having a full understanding of what was going on, so I dug around in the support library source code to try figure it out. At a very high level, I think this may be what is going on with setRetainInstance(true):

1. Fragment A is displayed, button is pressed and Fragment A is replaced by Fragment B. As part of this process, the FragmentManager (FM) removes Fragment A and `fragmentA.mRemoving` flag is set to true.
2. Change orientation the first time. At this point the FM attempts to save all state of the fragments:

   ```
   Parcelable saveAllState() {
   ...
   if (f.mState > Fragment.INITIALIZING && fs.mSavedFragmentState == null) {
               fs.mSavedFragmentState = saveFragmentBasicState(f);
   ```

   Fragment A has a CREATED state and has a null saved state, so it qualifies to have its state saved.
3. The activity is destroyed as part of the orientation change. Long story short, Fragment A has its state changed to INITIALIZING.
4. The activity is recreated and an attempt is made to move the state of the fragments to CREATED. However, at this point there is a check in the FM moveToState() method:

   ```
   if (f.mRemoving && newState > f.mState) {
       // While removing a fragment, we can't change it to a higher state.
       newState = f.mState;
   }
   ```

   Because `fragmentA.mRemoving` remains true from step 1 as the fragment was retained (not recreated), it does not have its state increased to CREATED but remains in the INITIALIZING state. Note that even if one presses the back key now, Fragment A will still have its state intact, as a result of its state being saved in step 2.
5. Change orientation for the 2nd time. Once again the FM attempts to save all state of the fragments:

   ```
   Parcelable saveAllState() {
   ...
   if (f.mState > Fragment.INITIALIZING && fs.mSavedFragmentState == null) {
               fs.mSavedFragmentState = saveFragmentBasicState(f);
   ```

   However, because Fragment A is in the INITIALIZING state it does not qualify to have its state saved. Hence, once orientation completes for the 2nd time, if the back key is pressed the state of Fragment A is no longer intact.

---

### Questions

1. Is this behaviour expected? Perhaps this relates to the documentation discouraging the use of setRetainInstance and backstack fragments?
2. How should we deal with view state and the use of setRetainInstance? Perhaps my use case is incorrect, but I would be nervous using the setRetainInstance functionality with this difference in behaviour.

Once again, sorry for the long post. Feedback will be appreciated as always.